# I cannot call my customized spinner XML into my mainactivity.java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have my spinner in the `mainActivity` like this (just in case, this spinner is different from the basic because it doesn't allow to click on items, it just shows the info):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Inicio metodo spinner

        Spinner planets_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this, **android.R.layout.spinner_item,** 

getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)){
```

And of course I have already create the `spinner_item.xml` that I have put in the layout folder:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bandes" /><!--Make sure image is present in Drawable folder-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

To sum up Android studio doesn't recognize the spinner_item in the java code.

I'm using API 25, android studio 2.2.3

Comment: add Your adapter class do not add half codes and half xmls :P

Comment: have you inflate your custom layout?

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by inflate custom layout

Comment: you want a spinner item with image and textView inside it so you need to customize the view and set it , otherwise you will get the normal spinner . what do you want normal one or items with images and textView one

Comment: read this http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84

Answer (score 2):

If you are Using Custom layout, i.e. spinner_item, then you should use this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this, ****R.layout.spinner_item**,**);
```

instead of

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this, **android.R.layout.spinner_item,**);
```

android.R.layout.spinner_item is used for default spinner.

Comment: right, you if you are using custom layout no need to write android before inflating layout.